# Program exits when players number of turns = 6. Python Battleship Game

Tags: python

I'm making a 2-player battleship game in python. I've made it so that each 'game' allows a total of 6 turns (3 from each player), after which a message will appear saying 'The number of turns has ended'.

Once this happens, they will be asked to play again. If they answer 'yes' or 'y', the game should reload. However it doesn't. The board loads but the program then exits. I believe the issue lies with my play_again() function but I'm not quite sure what it is.

I want to make it so that the players can play as many games as they want until they decide to answer 'no' or 'n'. How do I go about implementing this?

```
from random import randint


game_board = []

player_one = {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "wins": 0,
}

player_two = {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "wins": 0,
}

colors = {"reset":"\033[00m",
          "red":"\033[91m",
          "blue":"\033[94m",
          "cyan":"\033[96m"
              }


# Building our 5 x 5 board
def build_game_board(board):
    for item in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

def show_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

# Defining ships locations
def load_game(board):
    print("WELCOME TO BATTLESHIP!")
    print("Find and sink the ship!")
    del board[:]
    build_game_board(board)
    print(colors['blue'])
    show_board(board)
    print(colors['reset'])
    ship_col = randint(1, len(board))
    ship_row = randint(1, len(board[0]))
    return {
        'ship_col': ship_col,
        'ship_row': ship_row,
    }

ship_points = load_game(game_board)


# Players will alternate turns.
def player_turns(total_turns):

    if total_turns % 2 == 0:
        total_turns += 1
        return player_one

    return player_two

# Allows new game to start
def play_again():

    positive = ["yes", "y"] 
    negative = ["no", "n"]

    global ship_points

    while True:
        answer = input("Play again? [Y(es) / N(o)]: ").lower().strip()
        if answer in positive:
            ship_points = load_game(game_board)
            break

        elif answer in negative:   
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            exit()

# What will be done with players guesses
def input_check(ship_row, ship_col, player, board):
    guess_col = 0
    guess_row = 0
    while True:
        try:
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:")) - 1
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:")) - 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number only: ")
            continue
        else:
            break
    match = guess_row == ship_row - 1 and guess_col == ship_col - 1
    not_on_game_board = (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4)

    if match:
        player["wins"] += 1
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        print('The current match score is %d : %d (Player1 : Player2)' % (player_one["wins"], player_two["wins"]))
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        play_again()

    elif not match:
        if not_on_game_board:
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

        elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X" or board[guess_row][guess_col] == "Y":
            print("You guessed that one already.")

        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            if player == player_one:
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            else:
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "Y"

        print(colors['cyan'])
        show_board(game_board)
        print(colors['reset'])

    else:
        return 0


def main():
    begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')
    while (begin != str('start')):
        begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')

    for turns in range(6):

        if player_turns(turns) == player_one:
            print(ship_points)
            print("Player One")
            input_check(
                ship_points['ship_row'],
                ship_points['ship_col'],
                player_one, game_board
            )

        elif player_turns(turns) == player_two:
            print("Player Two")
            input_check(
                ship_points['ship_row'],
                ship_points['ship_col'],
                player_two, game_board
            )

        if turns == 5:
            print("The number of turns has ended.")
            print(colors['red'])
            show_board(game_board)
            print(colors['reset'])
            print('The current match score is %d : %d (Player1 : Player2)' % (player_one["wins"], player_two["wins"]))
            play_again()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also worked for me when I added an invocation to main in your play_again() function:

```
# Allows new game to start
def play_again():

    positive = ["yes", "y"] 
    negative = ["no", "n"]

    global ship_points

    while True:
        answer = input("Play again? [Y(es) / N(o)]: ").lower().strip()
        if answer in positive:
            ship_points = load_game(game_board)
            main()
            break

        elif answer in negative:   
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying `main` with:

```
turns = 0
while turns < 6:
    # Process turn...
    if turns == 5:
        # Show endgame board
        if play_again():
            turns = -1
    turns += 1
```

And have `play_again` return `True` on positive input `['y', 'yes']` and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `play_again()` call, upon receiving "Y" as answer, loads the board, but then simply returns. Where? Well, to the place it was called from - the for loop in `main()`. And unfortunately, it is the last iteration of said for loop, so the loop then ends and the program exits.

You should've put another loop around the for loop:

```
while True:
    for turns in range(6):
       ...
```